# Configuring Texmaker to find latex and other compilation tools / commands

Tags: errors, compiling, texmaker

I've installed latest releases of MiKTeX, GhostScript and Texmaker, but I can't compile anything. The error message "Could not run the command" appears. How do I configure it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Options -> Configure Texmaker` and change the paths for the programs. You can choose the correct one using the button on the right of the text field, and then copy the path with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for the other programs.

Comment: Should all the features be installed?

Comment: It is only a copy and paste ... If you did it not this time than you'll forget about it ... So it is save to do it for all.

Answer (score 2):

If you used the [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup) net installer (5.51 MB for version 2.9), make sure that the packages were installed and not just downloaded. This installer downloads packages just like the Cygwin installer. However, it does not install them automatically. You need to launch the installer again and tell it to install the downloaded packages. I recently installed MiKTeX on Win7 and had to go through this process. I recommend to :

- Check if MiKTeX is installed. The default installation directory is C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9.
- Check if `latex` is visible from your path by typing `latex --version` on the command line.

[image: MiKTeX installer screenshot]