# Selecting LaTeX Version in TeXmaker

Tags: installing, texmaker, linux

The Fedora 24 repository is stuck with the 2016/dev version of LaTeX, causing a number of compilation problems with several documents.

I've now manually installed TeXlive 2016, but I'm having problems selecting this version in TeXmaker.

The 2016/dev version is installed in `/usr/share/texlive`; the direct TeXlive install is found in `/usr/local/texlive`.

This question is addressed in [Configuring Texmaker to find latex and other compilation tools / commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9654/configuring-texmaker-to-find-latex-and-other-compilation-tools-commands), but the top answer is not specific enough to be helpful.

If someone could walk me through the "Configure Texmaker" window and how to find the specific programs, that would be great.

Apologies if this belongs in the Unix/Linux SE; this seemed to be right on the border, so I chose here.

Comment: What does `which pdflatex` returns in a terminal? And `pdflatex -version`?

Comment: Ha, `/usr/bin/pdflatex`!

Comment: And `pdflatex -version`? If I understand correctly, installed the "normal" texlive did not replace `/usr/bin/pdflatex`?

Comment: It appears it didn't, no; `pdflatex -version` returns 2016/dev.

Comment: ...the obvious question now being if I installed it incorrectly.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html? You could try again, after removing the two existing installations.

Comment: I did, in fact. I'll uninstall the two tonight and try again. I install it into `/usr/local/texlive`, no? And the script will take care of moving it to `/usr/bin` if necessary?

Comment: How did you adjust the path to use your new texlive? It sounds like it is wrong, and still give you the old one. Remember never make the adjustment in bashrc

Comment: @daleif That's what I'm trying to figure out, I think; I'm having trouble adjusting this path.

Comment: Did you set the `PATH`: see paragraph _Post-install: setting PATH_ on the previously provided link. `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/i386-linux:$PATH` (to be adapted and exported permanently).

Comment: Usually I'd just add it to `~\.profile` logout and in again. More or less like anderstood wrote, adjusted to fix your setup