# Dont get the quick build out

Tags: texmaker, viewers

I just installed the TexMaker for the first time on my new notebook. It wont be posible for me to get a quick view on the pdf file. It always pops up the same failure looks like the Edidor can not find a package, dont you think?

thanks for your help 
[image: Failure ino]

Comment: AFAIK TeXmaker is an editor. Do you also have a LaTeX installation? If not, it may  not be very surprising that `PDFLaTeX` cannot be executed.

Comment: It would be better to write the error message in the question, because the search engine can not read text in images. Here is a question of someone who had the same error message: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9654 . Make sure you install MikTeX or TeXLive, then try again.